GitHub show file preview with EOL Mac formatted
I have some files that use Mac's end of line format (CR).
I have pushed them on GitHub, however it doesn't seems to recognize the end of the line properly thus file preview is messed up.
I have already tried to set up .gitattributes file on root directory, but it doesn't work and I don't think is the right solution.
